# boost library can not be found

Tags: c++, boost

I have compiled boost version 1.47 using MinGW on winXP SP3. 
I included the path to the libraries (C:\boost\boost_1_47_0) in a linker variable in my make file. When run "make" in the command prompt window i get the following error message:

"c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1"

What could be the possible problem and how do i solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does `C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib` exist?

Comment: Could you try running the command line in admin mode?

Comment: @CharlesB: yes C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib exist and has files (with .dll, .dll.a, and .a extensions)

Comment: change permissions of C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\

Comment: @Gasim: I cannot find a way to change permissions on winXP SP3. I've tried "right-click then properties" but the dialog that comes does not seem to have much that has something to do with permissions.

Comment: @Bart: I'm actually running winXP as an administrator.

Comment: @Amani - right click the folder, select 'Sharing & Security'.  Security tab shows user permissions on the folder.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: yes a went as far as that but could not find a place specifically that could change the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out solution. Probably the problem was mine and note "make". Below is the make file that is now working.

```
# global variables
CC = g++
SRC = main.cpp
BOOST = C:\boost\boost_1_47_0
BOOSTLIB = C:\boost\boost_1_47_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mgw45-1_47.a

# linking
main : main.o
    $(CC) main.o $(BOOSTLIB) -o main 

# compile
main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) -c -I$(BOOST) $(SRC) -o main.o

# clean
clean :
    rm main.o main
```

Now it works. I'm not really sure, but probably the order of rules was not correct. Thanks for all the help.